# Dynamically Convert LINQ and Lambdas to SQL or Any Text

Tags: .net, sql, linq, t-sql, lambda

If anybody knows any parts of this question please answer it.

I'm developing a special data layer which should run SQL against database or sent a set of commands to a device. what I need is to process Lambda expressions and/or Linq queries and generate **MY** equivalent Sql or command set .

e.a :

```
var q= from myModel m select m Where m.Amount > 10
```

I want to process q to be able to generate text like these :

```
command #1
get map('myModel')
setCondition For Amount AS GreaterThan 10
execute #1
```

or

```
Select * FROM myModel WHERE Amount > 10
```

or

```
sp_myModelWhere('Amount','>',10)
```

Also I want to be able to process lambda expressions:
e.a :

```
DAL<myModel>.Where(p=>p.Amount > 10)
```

what is the code for abouve Where method?

Comment: You will have to implement your own LINQ Queryable provider. There is a project on codeplex to help with that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own LINQ Provider. Explaining this would probably be too extensive for a simple stackoverflow answer, but [here's a tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546158.aspx), and [here's another short walkthrough](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2007/10/04/writing-custom-linq-provider.aspx).